# android opening image into Gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview

I'm trying to open an image into the gallery (Or any other Apps that handle image opening)...

The problem is that it tells me it can't find the element... However, the image is correctly loaded when I call BitmapFactory.decodeFile().

Here's the code

```
    imgV = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.image);
    final String path = myApp.getAppContext().getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/media/" + Tools.toHexString(pmid) + "/" + md5 + ".jpg";
    imgV.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));
            imgV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);

                    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Does the value of md5 change by the time the onClick is called?

Comment: No, actually, I have created a new variable called path... using it on both decodeFile and uri.parse(), still the same... updating my question

Comment: Is it that the gallery doesn't have read permissions in the file path of your activity?

Comment: @spartygw : how to know ? how to give permissions ? (My file is in myApp data folder...)

Comment: Can you adb shell into it and chmod the dir to 755?

Comment: I have managed to cd until the folder I created 'media' which is unable to open... I'm trying to set the folder executable when creating it... But it doesn't seems to work :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your image to a directory on the SD card with world readable permissions and the gallery will be able to open it and display it.

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/myTmpDir/" + Tools.toHexString(pmid));
folder.mkdirs();

final String path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/myTmpDir/"+Tools.toHexString(pmid) + "/" + md5 + ".jpg");

imgV.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));
        imgV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);

                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```